# Does water in the environment affect the fire weapons of the Firebug or Husk?

Tags: killing-floor-2

Some maps, like Black Forest, feature bodies of water in its environment. Does water in the environment affect the fire weapons of the Firebug, and what about the Husk's fireball attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, water does ***NOT*** affect gameplay in any way.

I have almost 250 hours in this game and many times I have asked myself why standing under/in water doesnt douse the flames. You can even use groundfire (with or without perk) on water as firebug